# Hash table vulnerability (property overwrite)?

Tags: security, powershell

I was playing around with hash tables in PowerShell, and I noticed some odd behavior related to accessing items. As we know, PowerShell allows at least three different ways of assigning values to hash table entries:

```
$hashtable["foo"] = "bar"        #1
$hashtable.Item("foo") = "bar"   #2
$hashtable.foo = "bar"           #3
```

Meanwhile, we use the #3 syntax to access the properties of the Hashtable object itself, such as `Count`, `Keys`, `Values`, etc. And if we add an item with the key that conflicts with the name of an internal property, PowerShell allows us to do so, and we effectively are no longer able to read the value of the property (except using Reflection).

I guess that in a situation where the keys come from an untrustworthy source (e.g. from external file or network), this might have an undesired impact on flow control, and could probably be exploited by a malicious user.

This snippet demonstrates the issue:

```
function Get-HashtableProperties($hashTable, $header)
{
    "{0} {1} {0}" -f ("-" * 10), $header

    "Count                      : {0}" -f $hashtable.Count
    "Keys.Count                 : {0}" -f $hashtable.Keys.Count
    "Values.Count               : {0}" -f $hashtable.Values.Count
    "Actual Count (Reflection)  : {0}" -f $hashtable.GetType().GetProperty("Count").GetValue($hashtable)

    "`nItems (Keys iteration):"
    $hashtable.Keys | ForEach-Object { "  [ {0} = {1} ]" -f $_, $hashtable.Item($_) }

    "`nItems (Enumerator iteration):"
    $enumerator = $hashTable.GetEnumerator()
    while ($enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        "  [ {0} = {1} ]" -f $enumerator.Current.Key, $enumerator.Current.Value
    }
}

$fileContent = @"
    Foo = a
    Bar = b
"@

$maliciousFileContent = @"
    Foo = a
    Bar = b
    Count = 0
    Keys =
    Values =
"@

$hashtable = ConvertFrom-StringData $fileContent
$damagedHashtable = ConvertFrom-StringData $maliciousFileContent

Get-HashtableProperties $hashtable "Normal Hash Table"
Get-HashtableProperties $damagedHashtable "Damaged Hash Table"
```

Output:

```
---------- Normal Hash Table ----------
Count                      : 2
Keys.Count                 : 2
Values.Count               : 2
Actual Count (Reflection)  : 2

Items (Keys iteration):
  [ Bar = b ]
  [ Foo = a ]

Items (Enumerator iteration):
  [ Bar = b ]
  [ Foo = a ]
---------- Damaged Hash Table ----------
Count                      : 0
Keys.Count                 : 1
Values.Count               : 1
Actual Count (Reflection)  : 5

Items (Keys iteration):
  [  =  ]

Items (Enumerator iteration):
  [ Count = 0 ]
  [ Bar = b ]
  [ Foo = a ]
  [ Values =  ]
  [ Keys =  ]
```

**Question**: is there a way to protect against this issue, except manually checking every key before assignment and/or using Reflection everywhere in the code when we need to access the value of some `Hashtable` property?

Comment: You can create your own method to filter it out before adding? `foreach ($key in $wanttoadd) { if(!(CheckProtectedKeys($key)) { .... } }`. Why would you use a hashtable to store something called "Count"? Hashtables can only contain one item per key, and "count" is a name that sounds more like something you should use in a object(and collect in array). I see the problem, but I think it's easier to avoid those propertynames(which in my opinion aren't "hashtable"-material) in the first place. ^^

Comment: @Graimer: I agree that the chances of using "Count" as a hashtable key are pretty low, but this is a programming language semantics issue, and the language users are free to associate "Count" with whatever meaning they like. In my situation this question is rather theoretical, I would personally avoid this in a real script too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this sort of a scenario you can access the Hashtable's count property like so:

```
C:\PS> $ht = @{Count = 99}
$ht.psbase.Count
1
```

The extended type system in PowerShell offers several different views on an object via these PS* properties. See the [PowerShell team blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/11/24/what-s-up-with-psbase-psextended-psadapted-and-psobject.aspx) for details.

Comment: Which works until you get `$ht = @{ Count = 99; PSBase = 1..5 }` ;)  [`select`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113387) can help to access the underlying properties like `Count` and `Keys`, though not sure how to un-hide `PSBase` without removing the key from the table.

Comment: Yes but there is a reason why the team chose to prefix their ETS properties with "PS".  A collision with "PSBase" is much more corner case than "Count".  :-)