# Item overwrites method

Tags: powershell

I've got a JSon object that gets converted to a hash(table):

```
PS C:\> @{ "key1" = "1"; "key2" = "2" }.keys
key2
key1
```

everything great. but the generator of the JSon object decided for the following:

```
PS C:\> @{ "key1" = "1"; "keys" = "2" }.keys
2
```

which promptly breaks me.  it's astounding that this can happen.  Can anyone suggest how to make a hash safe?

TIA - e

Comment: See also: [Hash table vulnerability (property overwrite)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15122913/2495)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of conflicting/overriding property names you can always access the base object's properties using `psbase` e.g.:

```
PS C:\> @{ "key1" = "1"; "keys" = "2" }.psbase.keys
key1
keys
```

Comment: bloody awesome. if I could give you ten points I would! thanks mate